# When does Protractor actually execute tasks?

Tags: protractor

Protractor's documentation has a small summary of the control flow, where it says:

> WebDriverJS (and thus, Protractor) APIs are entirely asynchronous ... WebDriverJS maintains a queue of pending promises, called the control flow, to keep execution organized

[http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow][1]

When does the "queue of pending promises" actually get emptied? i.e., when do the tasks execute? (Where can I get a list of API calls that result in the queue to actually get processed?)

Comment: You mean Protractor API's ?

Comment: (I'm assuming this could be similar to Apache Spark, where there's a clear differentiation between "Transformations" and "Actions". Transformations  get en-queued and actions result in the computation of the pipeline)

Comment: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder

Here it is... Enjoy

Comment: @KishanPatel he's asking about promises and the control flow, not related to web elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protractor is built on top of WebdriverJS and you are right their API's are entirely asynchronous and return Promises!

These promises are based on the ControlFlow class which handle the execution of asynchronous tasks. Each task is scheduled via `ControlFlow execute()` method, which will return a `ManagedPromise` that will be resolved with the task's result.

For Detailed explanation you should read this [WebdriverJS Control Flow API doc](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html)